# Is it okay to use an OAuth2 authorization code as proof of a successful login?

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, flutterwebviewplugin

I have a database with emails and passwords, and a Flutter app that lets those users log into the app by providing their email and password (the old fashioned way).

Now, some of those users are part of an organization that has a separate website where they use Microsoft/Office 365 accounts to sign in. Of course they want to be able to log into my app using  their Office 365 accounts as well, instead of having to remember and type a different password in the app than they normally use on their organizations website.

So I've been looking at their website, which uses Microsoft Azure as a the backend. From their current login page I could find the `tenantID`, `clientID`, `redirectURL` and `scope`. From this I am able to get an authorization code back from the `login.microsoftonline.com` authorization endpoint. However, as my app is not registered in the organizations Azure account, I don't have a `clientSecret` so I can't call the token endpoint and get an `idToken`.

I'm using a WebView to display the login to their organizations website, so I can grab the authorization code from the redirect URL when they are redirected.

So my question is if I can use the authorization code directly to verify that the user has successfully signed in using their Office 365 account? All I need to know is that the user has an account at the organization, and that they could provide a valid email and password to login.

If they are redirected to the redirect URL with an autorization code, it means that they successfully logged in. Then I could consider them logged in to my app as well, based on the email provided to the Office 365 authorization endpoint. Because if they couldn't log in to their Office 365 they wouldn't get an authorization code, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the authorization code only has meaning to the identity provider, in this case Azure AD. It doesn't prove anything to your app.
What you could do is try `response_type=code+id_token` in the authorization URL.
If ID tokens have been configured as returnable from the authorization endpoint (this is done in the app registration configuration), you will get back a signed id token that you can verify.

Comment: Yeah I realize that that's the proper way to do it, and I would if the organization in question would set up their Azure config so that my app would have that kind of access. But I'm still curious if what I'm proposing is at all possible. You say that the authorization code has no meaning except to the identity server. What exactly is the authorization code? Can it be decoded somehow, or is it really just a random string?

Comment: At least I've never seen anything related to decoding it. I'm guessing it's encrypted by Azure AD.